# Nested span tag class not applied in xsl xml transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xml and XSLT transformation. My data is in xml and is being transferred to html using XSLT. I am using java program to transform. I have a made a simple xml and XSL to show the problem I am facing. The xml has the data for books. Each book's title and location is being displayed inside a table's td. There is a <?del_mark> tag inside the xml. This tag means, that the content specified in the data attribute of this tag needs to be enclosed inside a strike out and a P tag.

```
<?del-mark data="<tr><td>book 5 <span class="Dots"/></td><td>1005</td></tr>" />
```

In the stylesheet there is a template to handle the processing instruction (del_mark)and it takes the data attribute's value and replaces it inside a p and strike through tag. It is working fine, but in the final html, it is not replacing the `<span class="Dots"/>` with .... for the processing instruction template.

My problem is: There is a template for span tag which converts the span to dots using `<span class="Dots"/>`. This template is not getting used and the tag appear as is instead of dots as described in the template.

I have a java program which reads the sample xml and checks for the processing tag <?del_mark> and reads the data part of it and converts all the < and " to < and ". Then, this intermediate xml is used to as input xml for the transformation. The intermediate xml is also given below.

Please let me know if you need more info.

**SAMPLE XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <title>Book 1</title>
        <location>1000</location>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Book 2<span class="Dots"/>
        </title>
        <location>1002</location>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Book 3</title>
        <location>1003</location>
    </book>
    <?del_mark data=&quot;&lt;tr style=&quot;keep-with-next.within-page:always;&quot;>
        &lt;td width=&quot;280&quot;>
            &lt;p class=&quot;HangingIndent&quot;>Book&lt;span class=&quot;Dots&quot;/>
            &lt;/strike>
        &lt;/p>
        &lt;div style=&quot;margin:0 0 1em 0;&quot;>&lt;/div>
    &lt;/td>
    &lt;td align=&quot;center&quot; valign=&quot;bottom&quot; width=&quot;136&quot;>1004&lt;/td>
&lt;/tr>&quot;?>
    <book>
        <title>Book 5</title>
        <location>1005</location>
    </book>
</books>
```

** SAMPLE XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:math="java.lang.Math">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Books</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p> This a sample xml/xsl example<span class="Dots"/>
                </p>
                <table width="100%" border="1">
                    <THEAD>
                        <TR>
                            <TD width="35%">
                                <B>Title</B>
                            </TD>
                            <TD width="15%">
                                <B>Location</B>
                            </TD>
                        </TR>
                    </THEAD>
                    <TBODY>
                        <xsl:for-each select="books/book|books/processing-instruction()">
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </TBODY>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="location">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:span | span">

        <xsl:if test="@class='Spaces'">
      _________
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@class='Dots'">
      ..........
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('del_mark')">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<font color="yellow"><strike>]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="dval" select="substring-after(current(), 'data=')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="v1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$dval" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($v1, 2, string-length($v1) - 2)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</strike></font>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

** INTERMEDIATE XML **

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?><books>
    <book>
        <title>Book 1</title>
        <location>1000</location>

    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Book 2<span class="Dots"/>
        </title>
        <location>1002</location>

    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Book 3</title>
        <location>1003</location>

    </book>
    <?del_mark <p style="display:inline;">data="<tr style="keep-with-next.within-page:always;">
        <td width="280">
            <p class="HangingIndent">Book<span class="Dots"/>
            </strike>
        </strike></p><div style="margin:0 0 1em 0;"></div>
        <div style="margin:0 0 1em 0;"></div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="bottom" width="136">1004</td>
</tr>"?>

    <book>
        <title>Book 5</title>
        <location>1005</location>

    </book>
</books>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html xmlns:math="java.lang.Math" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <head>
      <title>Books</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p> This a sample xml/xsl example<span class="Dots"></span></p>
      <table width="100%" border="1">
         <THEAD>
            <TR>
               <TD width="35%"><B>Title</B></TD>
               <TD width="15%"><B>Location</B></TD>
            </TR>
         </THEAD>
         <TBODY>
            <tr>
               <td>Book 1</td>
               <td>1000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Book 2
               </td>
               <td>1002</td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Book 3</td>
               <td>1003</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><font color="yellow"><strike><tr style="keep-with-next.within-page:always;">
               <td width="280">
               <p class="HangingIndent">Book<span class="Dots"/>
               </strike>
               </strike></p><div style="margin:0 0 1em 0;"></div>
               <div style="margin:0 0 1em 0;"></div>
               </td>
               <td align="center" valign="bottom" width="136">1004</td>
               </tr></strike></font>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Book 5</td>
               <td>1005</td>
            </tr>
         </TBODY>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

IN the output html,  I want the row 4 data to be shown  as book 4... instead of book 4 `<span class="Dots"/>`.

```
<tr>
<td> book 4 .......</td>
<td>1004</td>
<tr>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The template for the `span` node isn't being applied firstly because you make no attempt to apply it using `xsl:apply-templates`, and secondly because there is in fact no `span` node in your document. There's only some data that would be turned into a `span` node if it were parsed as XML.

In modern versions of XSLT there is a `parse-xml()` function that allows you to turn the lexical XML in your processing instruction into a tree of nodes, which can then be processed in the normal way (for example using `xsl:apply-templates`). Processors implementing earlier versions of XSLT may have an extension function that does the same thing, or they may allow you to write your own (for example by calling out to Java).

In Saxon there is also an extension function `get-pseudo-attributes()` that allows you to extract the "data" pseudo-attribute of your PI.

So:

1. Extract the contents of the PI data as you do now:

   <xsl:variable name="dval" select="substring-after(current(), 'data=')"/>

and strip off the leading and trailing quotes.

2. Alternatively, use `saxon:get-pseudo-attribute('data')`
3. Call `parse-xml()` on the result
4. Call `apply-templates on the result.

So it could simply be:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('del_mark')">
  <font color="yellow">
    <strike>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
         select="parse-xml(saxon:get-pseudo-attribute('data')"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
    </strike>
  </font>
</xsl:template>
```

For a bit of extra modularity, I would put the template rule for `span` in a separate mode:

```
<xsl:mode name="nested-xml" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="span" mode="nested-xml">
 ...
</xsl:template>
```

and then

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
             select="parse-xml(saxon:get-pseudo-attribute('data')"
             mode="nested-xml"
             xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try out parse-xml function for processing instructions. Please can you help me with code change to get the span tag with dots class to work inside the processing instruction. I am still new to xsl and trying to understand the concept.

Comment: Appreciate the timely response. I did try all these, but I am having issue. what imports to use. Also, googled but couldn't resolve it.  I get the following error when I refer to select="parse-xml(saxon:get-pseudo-attribute('data')" in my code as mentioned. I changed the xslt version to 3.1 and  still it ditn't fix the issue. In  java side, we use saxon9 and saxon9-dom jar files. Error at xsl:apply-templates on line . column 
  XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 45 on line 84 in {...:get-pseudo-attribute('data...}:
    Unknown system function parse-xml()

Comment: My xsl namespaces imports are `code`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:math="java.lang.Math">`code`

Comment: The name saxon9.jar was used for 10 major releases from 9.0 to 9.9 over a period of about 10 years, so it doesn't actually tell us which version you are using; but saxon-dom.jar was dropped quite a while ago so you're probably using something pretty old. Running it with the -t version will tell you. Time to upgrade to a more recent version. Current version is 12.3. The namespace declarations in the stylesheet (and the version in the stylesheet) tell you nothing about what XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: Thank you. Will try with the newer version of saxon jar.